# SQL Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
->  Emp_No          INT(4),
->  Emp_Fname       VARCHAR(50),
->  Emp_Lname     VARCHAR(50),
->  Job_Class               VARCHAR(4),
->  PRIMARY KEY     (Emp_No),
->  FOREIGN KEY (Job_Class) REFERENCES JOB (Job_Class)
->  );
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT(
->  Pro_No       INT(4),
->  Pro_Name                VARCHAR(50),
->  Pro_Leader     VARCHAR(50),
->  Emp_No       INT(4),
->  PRIMARY KEY (Pro_No),
->  FOREIGN KEY (Emp_No) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Emp_No)
->  );
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)

```
CREATE TABLE ASSIGN(
->  Pro_No       INT(4),
->  Emp_No          INT(4),
->  Job_Class    VARCHAR(4),
->  Assign_Hours       DECIMAL(6,2),
->  Total_Charge        DECIMAL(6,2),
->  PRIMARY KEY (Pro_No, Emp_No),
->  FOREIGN KEY (Pro_No) REFERENCES PROJECT (Pro_No),
->  FOREIGN KEY (Emp_No) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Emp_No)
->  );
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (Emp_No, Emp_Fname, Emp_Lname, Job_Class) VALUES ('101', 'John','New','DD');
```

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
> (`o_m_m`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Job_Class`) REFERENCES `job` (`Job_Class`))

Can anyone please help me, my sql was working fine

I was missing     ->  FOREIGN KEY (Job_Class) REFERENCES JOB (Job_Class) in EMPLOYEE which I added and populated

now I receive this error

Comment: Does Job_class =DD exist in Job table ?

Answer (score 0):

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
>   central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
>   back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child
>   table.
>
> It will reject any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create
>   a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching
>   candidate key value in the parent table.

Perhaps, you are attempting to insert a foreign key value in child table that doesn't exist in your parent table.

Courtesy: [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)